# Org-mode: set latex attribute in code generated image

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

I generate some image through babel code block for a beamer presentation

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file qt_unit2_observer.eps :noexport
@startuml
Observer --> Observable : register
Observable -> Observer : notify
@enduml
#+END_SRC
```

This is perfectly fine and generates a result

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:qt_unit2_observer.eps]]
```

Now, I'd like to add some latex attributes to this image like this

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :height 30mm
```

but the only way it works is if I put this immediately before the image link

```
#+RESULTS:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :height 30mm
[[file:qt_unit2_observer.eps]]
```

but this is messed up the next time I regenerate the image

```
#+RESULTS:
[[file:qt_unit2_observer.eps]]
#+ATTR_LATEX: :height 30mm
[[file:qt_unit2_observer.eps]]
```

is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if I put `#+ATTR_LATEX: :height 30mm` right before the `#+RESULTS:` line.

Comment: Thank you @rvf0068 it worked perfectly! I wish there was some documentation about this case